# How to test relative positions of samples under different conditions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, repeated-measures

Suppose that I have a 2-dimensional space whose dimensions are named $D_1$ and $D_2$ (such as "height" and "weight"). $N$ samples are located in this space by measuring $D_1$ and $D_2$ for each of them under a certain condition $C_1$. In this space I can compute the relative positions of the samples with some distance measure. Then I measure $D_1$ and $D_2$ under a different condition $C_2$ and I see that the positions of the samples slightly change. I want to check if the change in relative positions (i.e., did samples that were close to each other remain close? And so on) is statistically relevant. What is the best approach?

Comment: A "2-dimensional space" *a fortiori* has two dimensions.  Evidently then the $D_i$ refer to "dimension" in a different sense.  Are you trying to say you have samples located within some rectangle of size $D_1\times D_2$? Does your sense of "relative position" include *orientation* (as implied by the word "position") or is it limited just to the *distance* between the objects?  When the samples change, in what sense would that change the $D_i$, which appear to describe the *space* and not the samples?

Comment: $D_1$ and $D_2$ are just the name of the dimensions, i.e. "height" and "weight". Relative position is related to the distance